# MySQL Compare Dates with time difference

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

Is there a way to compare a datetime field in mySQL with the current date and return the time difference? I don't really know where to start so if anyone has an idea, please point me to the right direction.

Here's what I already tried.

```
SELECT *
FROM  `order` 
WHERE  `dateTimeAdded` - NOW( ) <1;
```

basically what I am trying to achieve is to get the orders which is saved for more than 8 hours in the database. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want your query to have a chance of using an index on the datetime column, you should not do manipulation (functions) on the column but only on the other side:

```
SELECT *
FROM  `order` 
WHERE  dateTimeAdded < NOW( ) - INTERVAL 8 HOUR ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If u just need the diff of dates use
DATEDIFF(now(), column)

and if you need the time difference use 
TIMEDIFF(now(),column)

Comment: Thanks. So meaning `SELECT * FROM order WHERE TIMEDIFF(NOW(), dateTimeAdded) <= 8;` should give me the row/s which are 8 hours old and less?

Answer (score 1):

```
DATEDIFF(date1,date2);
```

Taken [FROM](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp)